# qv4l2 no longer controls zoom level

Tags: video

I use qv4l2 to adjust my logitech camera. Under "user control" it used to let me zoom, but now it only has brightness, contrast, etc. I don't know what changed. I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 not that long ago, but I'm not really sure when I lost the zoom feature.

I have a small green screen behind me and need to zoom in a bit to not go off the virtual background.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had recently added a firestick, which became /dev/video0, and qv4l2 was defaulting to it. The webcam that zoom uses became /dev/video2. qv4l2 does not show a camera control option for video0 which is not a camera. I hadn't realized the gui was telling me about the wrong device. I now start qv4l2 with -d /dev/video2 which has camera controls.